# How to plot a one column data frame with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like this:

```
 __________
|   | sums |
|---+------|
| a | 122  |
|---+------|
| b | 23   |
|---+------|
| c | 321  |
|__________|
```

*Notice "a","b" and "c" are row names.

I would like to see a plot like this:

```
                    ___
300 -|             |   |
200 -|  ___        |   |
100 -| |   |  ___  |   |
  0 -|_|___|_|___|_|___|______
         a     b     c
```

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the rownames as a column in the data frame and then plot. Here's an example with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(rownames_to_column(mtcars[1:3,], var="Model"), 
       aes(x=Model, y=mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.5, hjust=0))
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that works, the only problem is I have 30 variables, and the labels are all on top of each other. I found this from another SO post: `ggplot(df.m, aes(value)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill=variable), position="dodge")` How can I combine the two?

Comment: was `ggplot(cbind(Model = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)[1:3, ], ...` not sufficient?

Comment: Well, I was already in the `tidyverse`, so I thought I'd drop in on `tibble` before heading back to my own dimension.

Answer (score 5):

Just try this:

```
df
   sums
a  122
b   23
c  321

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=rownames(df), sums)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]